# Is there an online LyX to TeX converter?

Tags: lyx, conversion

My laptop with LyX on it is suddenly out of commission.  For the short term I only have access to some heavily controlled university computers which have LaTeX but not LyX.  I want to convert some LyX files to TeX so I can edit and print them in the short term.  (I understand the edits cannot be put (easily) back into LyX format.  That is ok.)

My Question:
Does anyone know of an online converter that can convert from LyX 2.0 format to LaTeX?

Comment: Related: [LyX Portable Installations](http://wiki.lyx.org/Windows/PortableInstallation)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

My advice would be to first check the cluster computers (e.g. the ones students have access to, such as in libraries). I know at some universities (e.g. Princeton) there is access in some clusters. If it is not there, you could ask the IT to install it. Remind them that it is free and open source so there are no license or cost issues.

Here are some other options:

You can try this webapp, which claims to support LyX. We had one user who claims it works:
https://www.rollapp.com/app/lyx

I imagine you can still use SSH from your computer? If so, you could just spin up an Amazon server and connect to that. LyX can export to .tex on the command line:

```
lyx -e latex file.lyx
```

You could try tunneling through X and using a GUI, which I have done and it works, but it might be slow depending on your connection.

Lastly, you could try to find an online implementation of [MultiMarkdown-4](https://github.com/fletcher/MultiMarkdown-4), which claims to supports LyX, but I imagine it does not have full support.

Comment: I just found out the Penn State Library computers have LyX.  Nonetheless your answer is awesome and I am sure others in a bind will find it of value.